# Items recompose during scrolling list

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, compose-recomposition

On my screen I have `MyTopItem()` and below list with items.
When I'm starting scrolling my list I want to hide `MyTopItem()`.

It works fine but scrolling is so laggy.
It happens because during scrolling all items in `MyLazyVerticalGridItemsSection()` recompose.

How can I avoid recomposing during scrolling?

```
Column(Modifier.fillMaxSize()) {
    val listState = rememberLazyListState()

    AnimatedVisibility(
        visible = listState.firstVisibleItemScrollOffset < 1,
        enter = expandVertically(),
        exit = shrinkVertically()
    ) {
        MyTopItem()
    }
    MyLazyVerticalGridItemsSection(
        items = myItems,
        listState = listState
    )
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This happens because you're using `listState.firstVisibleItemScrollOffset` directly, so each time this value changes, the recomposition is triggered.

In such cases [`derivedStateOf`](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/compose/runtime/package-summary#derivedStateOf(kotlin.Function0)) should be used - it will only trigger recomposition when the result of the calculation changes::

```
val visible by remember { derivedStateOf { listState.firstVisibleItemScrollOffset < 1 } }
```

Comment: Scrolling is less laggy but still not smooth. I've added to each list item number = (0..100).random() and when I scroll that number is changing in each item so I guess recomposition still happens during scrolling (?) Is it fine or there is better solution to handle that case?

Comment: @Wafi_ck there many other reasons why it can lag, for example it may lag in debug mode, try running the release version. But for sure it shouldn't recompose during scrolling - well only new appearing items should compose; it's hard to say without [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: Yeah, I've checked that on another screen and your solution works as expected. Thanks!

Comment: I"ve had to declare listState and visible at he the top of my screen.

Comment: I know this is late, but for future readers of this answer, the `derivedStateOf` needs to be wrapped with a `remember`